# Audio problems when resizing video - moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am resizing an mp4 video with this code (moviepy):

```
video_clip = VideoFileClip(url)
resized = video_clip.resize(width=720)
d = tempfile.mkdtemp()
video_path = os.path.join(d, 'output.mp4')
resized.write_videofile(video_path)
```

The resized clip's audio works when I play it on my pc, but not on an iPhone. (The original clip's audio does work on my iPhone.)

How can I fix this?

First image: Codec of resized video 
Second image: Codec of original video

[image: Codec of resized video]
[image: Codec of original video]

Comment: First, please do not post pictures of text. Second what is the pixel format? Did you accidentally convert to 4:4:4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it working:

```
resized.write_videofile(video_path, temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```